# Change View height after translation animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

In my activity I have a `BottomNavigationView` and a `RecyclerView`, and what I want to do is to hide the `BottomNavigationView` when I scroll the view, I'm using this code:

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                BottomNavigationView navigationView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

                if (recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && dy > 0){
                    navigationView.animate()
                            .translationY(navigationView.getHeight());
                }
                else if(recyclerView.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING && dy < 0)
                    navigationView.animate()
                            .translationY(0);
            }



        });
```

This works fine except for the fact that it still shows the bounds of the view, so after hiding the `BottomNavigationView` I get an empty rectangle. What is the best way to make the height of the view follow the translation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your "hiding" `BottomNavigationView`

but if your using

`BottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

which hides the view but keeps its width and height.

it needs to be

`BottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

which hides the view and makes the width = 0 and height = 0

Comment: In the code there is a Y translation of the height of the navigation view, which "hides" the view but the bound of the view are still there, just a blank view